# Best way to close service client in asynchronous event scheme of things

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service client implemented using the asynchronous event (using `/async` and `/tcv:Version35` in svcutil).

What is the best way to manage the service client?

I am creating a new service client on each request and closing the service client when the event delegate returns. Is it good practice to create a new service client on each request? If I try to use the same service client then I have to de-register the event handlers to every request once the request is furnished (which somehow does not look like an elegant way to achieve this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your services are stateless/sessionless then it's a good practice to create a service request and close/dispose them after use.

see this link on [how to properly dispose a WCF service client](http://blog.genom-e.com/PermaLink,guid,b9e3019d-0d68-4344-9c7a-407774323d0f.aspx)